# Linking static libnspr4 problems

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker

Visual Studio 2010 is linking libnspr4.lib successfully, but it looks like its not a static lib, but an implib because `lib.exe /LIST libnspr4.lib` outputs a lot of libnspr4.dll 
strings

The thing is I need to use PR_GetError() from it, but compiler adds a libnspr4.dll dependency to my dll`s Import Directory, and I dont want to distribute libnspr4.dll with my app

So I tried to link with libnspr4_s.lib(static lib) too, same result, I'm just confused, why is visual studio adding this libnspr4.dll dependency at my dll's Import Directory?

Comment: These should be posted as separate questions.

Comment: ok i'm sorry i didn't know that

Comment: When you added libnspr4_s.lib, did you remember to remove libnspr4.lib?

Comment: hey raymond, when i remove libnspr4.lib i get a "error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__PR_GetError"

Comment: No worries; I've removed the second question, you can post it separately.

Comment: This is one of those "so what did you expect?" type of things. If you don't want a dependency on libnspr4.dll, then you cannot use libnspr4.lib. If removing libnspr4.lib creates problems, you have to find a way to solve them without adding libnspr4.lib back, because once you add libnspr4.lib back, you get a dependency on libnspr4.dll

Comment: You might also want to ask about the unresolved external symbol issue on whatever support forums / websites the libnspr folks may provide.  They're more likely to know what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I want help of you guys to help me to understand something I do not understand now. Please, correct me if i`m wrong, but When we link libnspr4.lib(implib) with my.dll, compiler adds libnspr4.dll to my.dll import directory(IAT), linking with libnspr4_s.lib(static lib) shouldn't compiler "paste" the assembly code of PR_GetError in my.dll and we get undependent mmaping libnspr4.dll into mydll.dll address space?